# Convert single-column txt with 300 million rows to NumPy array faster

Tags: python, numpy, performance, file-io

I have a txt file that contains more than 300 million rows with 1 column. I'm trying to read and convert it to numpy array. Currently I have tried

```
label = np.loadtxt('/path/to/file')
```

and

```
for lines in fileinput.input('/path/to/file'):
    do_something_with(lines)
```

It seems `np.loadtxt` has a slightly faster performance but it still needs hours to read a single txt file. The file has more than 300 million rows with 1 column, but its size is only around 950 MB. I'm suspecting that `np.loadtxt` is also reading the file line by line which causes the processing time to be long.

I'm wondering if there is any method that can speed up this reading and converting process while keeping the sequence of the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the file is simple enough that `readlines` may work

Make a small sample file:

```
In [2]: arr = np.random.random((100,1))
In [4]: np.savetxt('test.txt', arr, fmt='%f')
In [6]: !head test.txt
0.872225
0.365394
0.802365
0.140455
0.041390
0.531483
0.415459
0.906439
0.789604
0.493369
```

The straightforward `loadtxt`:

```
In [8]: arr1 = np.loadtxt('test.txt')
In [9]: arr1.shape
Out[9]: (100,)
```

I think there's a parameter to force a (100,1) shape, I leave that for now.

Let's try a `readlines`, using `np.array` to convert the list of strings to float array:

```
In [11]: arr2 = np.array(open('test.txt').readlines(), dtype=float)
In [12]: arr2.shape
Out[12]: (100,)
In [13]: np.allclose(arr1,arr2)
Out[13]: True
```

Compare times:

```
In [14]: timeit arr2 = np.array(open('test.txt').readlines(), dtype=float)
77.5 µs ± 961 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [15]: timeit arr1 = np.loadtxt('test.txt')
605 µs ± 1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

A lot faster with readlines.

Another approach is `fromfile`:

```
In [18]: arr3 = np.fromfile('test.txt',dtype=float, sep=' ')
In [19]: arr3.shape
Out[19]: (100,)
In [20]: np.allclose(arr1,arr3)
Out[20]: True
In [21]: timeit arr3 = np.fromfile('test.txt',dtype=float, sep=' ')
118 µs ± 4.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Not quite as fast, but still better than `loadtxt`.  Yes, `loadtxt` reads the file line by line.

`genfromtxt` is a bit better than `loadtxt`.

`pandas` is supposed to have a fast csv reader, but that doesn't seem to be the case here:

```
In [33]: timeit arr4=pd.read_csv('test.txt',header=None).to_numpy()
1.12 ms ± 26.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Dear @hpaulj  thanks a lot for your answer. the readlines function is indeed way faster; what about if my data has three columns. I know that in the fileinput.input method I could use line.rstrip() and line.split(' '), but I'm not very how to do this based on your solution. By the way, the 3 column dataset has a size of 11 gb. I'm wondering if readlines() will cause a memory error. Thanks a lot for your kindness.